# Если размер динамического массива задан числом, которое больше 2, то происходит сбой программы

Tags: c++

*Программа должна считать модуль вектора по заданным координатам. переменная "num" задаёт размер динамического массива и кол-во координат вектора. В методе "GetCoord" массив заполняется координатами. Странности происходят в методе "calc", где происходят окончательные вычисления: подсчёт суммы квадратов координат и вычисление квадратного корня из полученного числа. Если задать кол-во координат(размерность массива) равное 2, то всё работает исправно, однако при задании переменной "num" числа большего чем 2 получаются какие-то фокусы: либо результат остаётся пустым и "ModVector.exe вызвал срабатывание точки останова", либо крашится программа.*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
class Vector {
private:
    double count;
    int num;
    int* CoordArr = new int[num];
public:
    Vector() :count(0), num(0) {};
    int dimension();
    int GetCoord();
    double calc();
};

int Vector::dimension() {
    cout << "Введите размерность пространства ";
    cin >> num;
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}

int Vector::GetCoord() {
    cout << "Введите координаты вектора поочерёдно "<<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        cin >> CoordArr[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}

double Vector::calc() {
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        count += pow(CoordArr[i],2);
    }
    cout << "Результат вычисления: ";
    cout << sqrt(count);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"russian");
    Vector vect;
    vect.dimension();
    vect.GetCoord();
    vect.calc();
    return 0;
}'
```

Comment: "Если задать кол-во координат(размерность массива) равное 2, то всё работает исправно" боюсь вас огорчить, но не работает, просто иногда результат неисправной программы совпадает с ожидаемым (очень неприятное свойство UB - неопределенного поведения).

Comment: @Slava 
Ну, я сейчас с калькулятором в руках: вроде все выходит, как и при ручных подсчётах, либо я не понял, что вы имели ввиду. .-.

Comment: Дело не в том, что там выходит, а в том, что вы вылезаете за пределы массива, просто в данной ситуации при значении индекса меньше 2 это не ломает программу, но это не делает ее правильной.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что инициализация динамического массива происходит в конструкторе класса `Vector` в этой строке:

Vector vect;

далее вы в методе `Vector::dimension()` меняете `n`, но память при этом не пересоздастся магически, указатель `CoordArr` как указывал на результат операции `new int[0]` так и продолжает указывать. Самый простой способ исправить - запрашивать `n` вне класса и передавать его конструктору при создании:

```
Vector( int n ) :count(0), num(n) {};
```

и далее в `main()`

```
int n = 0;
cout << "Введите размерность пространства ";
cin >> n;
Vector vect( n );
```

То, что программа у вас "работала" для 2х, просто совпадение, при других условиях она и при 2х работать не будет, поскольку вы всегда инициализировали указатель адресом массива нулевого размера.

Кроме того вы нарушаете известное [правило трех](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D1%82%D1%80%D1%91%D1%85_(C%2B%2B)). На визуальном поведении программы это не скажется, но у вас прямо сейчас утечка памяти. Поэтому лучше сразу эту ситуацию исправить, тем более она требует минимальных усилий. А лучше сразу использовать "умный" указатель.

Comment: Еще лучше использовать https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray который автор пытается сколхозить или в крайнем случае, std::vector